# What might cause the heating to get "stuck" off regardless of room thermostat?

Tags: wiring, central-heating, boiler

What could cause my heating system to get "stuck" in a state where the boiler will no longer come on in response to the room thermostat, and I can only seem to "fix" it by turning the property power on and off again?

I have the following home heating components:

- Worcester Bosch Greenstar RI boiler.
- Siemens RWB2E controller.
- Honeywell T6360 room thermostat.
- Honeywell V4073A Motorised Midposition Diverter Valve.
- Hot water tank with thermostat.

### How I get the system "stuck"

My start position is as follows:

- Set room stat to max (so switch is on).
- Set controller heating AND hot water to "Twice" but not in active time period.
- Turn house power on and off (to "reset" the system).

The I do this:

- Wind controller clock to first period of day.
- Boiler fires.
- Wind to end of first period.
- Boiler stops.
- **Turn heating to OFF on controller (from Twice)**
- Wind controller clock to second period of day.
- **Boiler does not come on, but should for heating!**
- **Playing with the room stat does not cause boiler get "unstuck" and fire.**
- Heating will not work again until power reset.

Summary:  If the controller clicks off when Heating and Hot Water are ON, Heating will never come back on.

**Does heating work on its own?**  Yes.  If I reset the system and have Hot Water OFF, turning the clock will bring the boiler on correctly for the Heating.  I can turn the clock through many cycles and the boiler will come on AND respond to the room stat.

*I've recently had the boiler replaced.  The room stat is also new, as is the motorised valve.*

Comment: There is a forced delay when the thermostat shuts off. This is so that poorly designed thermostats don't cause the heating system to constantly cycle on and off.

Comment: @BradGilbert which component are you saying has the forced delay?